# Ajax success is not working on nested .ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having an ajax that is within another .ajax.
While the success code is triggered on the fist ajax (`url: "get_hours.php"`), for some reason it is not triggered in the second case (`url: "send.php"`). I can confirm that the code within `"send.php"` is executed correctly, however `self.close();` is not working. Also, if I execute the `self.close();` before the second .ajax it does work. In addition, I have tried to add an alert in the second success, which is not firing as well.

**Here is my code**

```
$('#mydiv').datepicker({
            weekStart: 1,
            language: "bg"
        });

        var fid = $('#fid').val();
        var procedure = $('#procedure').val();

        $('#mydiv').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
            var full_date = $("#mydiv").datepicker('getDate');
            var year_month = full_date.getFullYear() + '-' + (full_date.getMonth() + 1); // Y-n-j in php date() format
            var day = '0'+full_date.getDate(); // Y-n-j in php date() format
            var date = year_month+'-'+day.slice(-2);

            $('#text').val(date);
            $('#result').html('Date: ' + date);
            $('#container').fadeOut().empty();

            var time ='';
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', true).css('display', 'none');
            $('#loading').css('display', 'block');

            $.ajax({
                url: "get_hours.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    date: date,
                    fid: fid,
                    procedure: procedure
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#container').empty();
                            $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
                            $('#container').append(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
                            $('.cell').on('click', function() {
                            $('.cell').removeClass('select');
                            $(this).addClass('select');
                            var time = $(this).text();
                            var date = $('#text').val();

                if (time != '') {
                  $('#submit').prop('disabled', false).css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                  alert(date + time);
                }

                            $('#result').html('Date: ' + date + ', Time: ' + time);
                            var account = "<? echo $account; ?>";
                            var userid = "<? echo $userid; ?>";
                            $('#submit').click(function() {

                                //self.close();

                                var date = $('#text').val();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "send.php",
                                    method: "POST",
                                    data: {
                                        date: date,
                                        time: time,
                                        account: account,
                                        userid: userid
                                    },
                                    success: function(data_sent) {
                                        self.close();
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    },500);   }
            });
        });
```

Tried to search for an answer here, but could find anything that could help me really.
So, any ideas are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `$('#submit').click(function() {` doesn't actually trigger as you haven't clicked it yet.

Comment: What do you mean? It does trigger on a submit button I have. Also, it does trigger as it executes the code in the send.php which is withing the `$('#submit').click` function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that the success is not working only with send.php file. If I use another file it works fine. I guess it is something with the curl response I have in the send.php file.